# How to split the export of a sql query with fputcsv

Tags: php, csv, row, multiple-columns, fputcsv

I have a simple fputcsv command for my sql query. But sometimes my export has more lines and different primary keys. My wish is to split every result with a different primary key to a new csv export.

Example:

```
| *row 1   | row 2   | row 3   |
|.......27 |......45 |......aa |
|.......27 |......35 |......ab |
|.......28 |......85 |......bb |
|.......28 |......65 |......bc |
```

Actual situation: The row 1 has the primary key (order_id). I run a cronjob every day with all orders. So the file has more than one order (as the example above = order 27, order 28 etc.). My supplier needs for each order a csv file. So i need a code, who split the query in something like "if order_id is different so create a new file...and so on...". Is this possible?

```
<?php
$servername = "Jarvis";
$username = "TonyStark";
$password = "iLoveIronMan";
$dbname = "TheAnvengers";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT o.order_id, o.customer_id, op.quantity, op.model FROM oc_order o INNER JOIN oc_order_product op ON o.order_id = op.order_id INNER JOIN oc_product p ON op.product_id = p.product_id WHERE o.order_status_id = 2 AND p.location = 1 ORDER BY o.order_id, op.model";

$file = fopen('../files/in/filename.csv', 'w');
if ($rows = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
        fputcsv($file, $row, ';');
    }
    mysqli_free_result($rows);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Your code is clear enough but please be more explicit with what you are trying to achieve, like an example SQL result and the CSV file(s) you would like to get out of it.

Comment: Thank you. Done in the original post above ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// connect to the database
$servername = "Jarvis";
$username = "TonyStark";
$password = "iLoveIronMan";
$dbname = "TheAnvengers";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Get the data
$sql = "SELECT o.order_id, o.customer_id, op.quantity, op.model FROM oc_order o INNER JOIN oc_order_product op ON o.order_id = op.order_id INNER JOIN oc_product p ON op.product_id = p.product_id WHERE o.order_status_id = 2 AND p.location = 1 ORDER BY o.order_id, op.model";

$orders = array();    // For storing the data by order_id

// Loop through the result set and populate $orders
if ($rows = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {

        // This is where the split on order_id occurs 
        $orders[$row['order_id']][] = $row;

        /*
            $orders will now look like this after the first iteration
            $orders = array(
                 27 => array(
                     0 => array(
                         'order_id' => 27,
                         'customer_id' => 45,
                         'quantity' => aa,
                         'model' => someModel
                     )
                 )
            );

            ==============================

            $orders will look like this after the last iteration
            $orders = array(
                 27 => array(
                     0 => array(
                         'order_id' => 27,
                         'customer_id' => 45,
                         'quantity' => aa,
                         'model' => someModel
                     ),
                     1 => array(
                         'order_id' => 27,
                         'customer_id' => 35,
                         'quantity' => ab,
                         'model' => someModel
                 ),
                 28 => array(
                     0 => array(
                         'order_id' => 28,
                         'customer_id' => 85,
                         'quantity' => bb,
                         'model' => someModel
                     ),
                     1 => array(
                         'order_id' => 28,
                         'customer_id' => 65,
                         'quantity' => bc,
                         'model' => someModel
                 )

            );


        */

    }
    mysqli_free_result($rows);
}
mysqli_close($conn);

// Loop through $orders (by order_id)
foreach($orders as $id => $order)
{
    // Open the file for writing, blanking existing file or creating if non-existent - name it after the order_id
    $f = fopen('../files/in/' . $id . '.csv', 'w');

    // Loop through each $row for that particular order_id and put it into the csv
    foreach($order as $entry)
    {
        fputcsv($f, $entry, ';');
    }

    fclose($f);
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you kidding me? This is the solution for my two problems! Thank you very much. It works. Only for understanding your answer: Where is the part who splits the results by order_id?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use order_id as the filename, move the `fopen` and `fclose` into the loop, and change `fopen` to work in append mode.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have already a post with this wish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666174/php-sql-value-as-filename. But this will not solve my problem. The supplier needs for each order a separate csv and the database has many orders in the same list.